# Is CNN capable of extracting the descriptive statistics features

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I was trying to build a CNN model. I used time series data of daily temperature to predict if there is risk of an event, say bacteria growth. **I calculated the descriptive statistics of the time series, ie. mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis etc for each observation and added them to input data.**

My question:

Is CNN capable of extracting the effect of the descriptive statistics the label, meaning that adding these descriptive statistics features manually does not make a difference?
(I will still try this later, but like to hear what you think about it). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is capable of catching them if they are statistics of the other variables, but you should still add them if you think those statistics are relevant IRL. The neural network might not choose to use them and go for overfitting other features instead.

Comment: What if they are statistics of time series data which is already part of input data?